# Redirect temp Loop error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I try to redirect my website from / to /complete/.

So I have modified the .htaccess by the way :

```
Redirect temp / http://www.example.com/complete/
```

but I get a loop problem. When I access to the adresse, I get the following :

```
http://www.example.com/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/?url=/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/&url=/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/&url=/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/&url=/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/&url=/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/&url=/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/&url=/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/&url=/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/&url=/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/&url=/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/&url=/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/&url=/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/&url=/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/&url=/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/&url=/complete/complete/complete/complete/complete/&url=/complete/complete/complete/complete/&url=/complete/complete/complete/&url=/complete/complete/&url=/complete/
```

Has someone any idea how to correct this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^complete /complete%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```